# Django 2: Migration with data that doesn’t exist in another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I’m trying to create a new table and load it with initial values that don’t currently exist in another table. All of the migration information that I have found is to pull from an existing model into a new model. I want to put new information in a new model. For example:

If I want a “Country Model” and a “State Model” with a foreign key to the country, how do I make a “Country(US)” with all of the states that go with that country?

And then if I later create “Country(Canada)” with all the territories in the same file as “US”, will it only add “Canada” or will it duplicate all of the “US” information.

Sorry for the bad format. I’m currently typing on my iPhone and haven’t figured out the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a management command and the initialise the database via a manage.py call?  Something like

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from .models.places import State, City

states = [
    ['Alabama','AL'],
    ['Alaska','AK'], ...
]

cities = [
    ['New York', 'New York'],
    ['Los Angeles', 'California'],
    ['Chicago','Illinois'], ...
]

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Populates the database with startup data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for s in states:
            state, created = State.objects.get_or_create(state=s[0],state_code=s[1])
            state.save()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('State "%s" created' % (state)))

        for c in cities:
            state = State.objects.get(state=c[1])
            city, created = City.objects.get_or_create(city=c[0],state=state)
            city.save()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('City "%s" created' % (city)))
```

Comment: Here's what I finally ended up with. [migration] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296739/django-python-how-to-iterate-through-a-list-in-a-dictionary-for-migration?noredirect=1#comment87611276_50296739)